# Free drawing in OpenGL

Tags: android, canvas, opengl-es, google-cast

I have been trying to create an freedrawing app in OpenGL. This was because I tried to create a paint app for the chromecast remote display. I was told that I should use the openGL shared renderer to refresh the chromecast and show my drawing. I was using a canvas back then but I just could not get it working together. That is why I tried to make paint in openGL but I just don't seem to get anything working.

So i have a few question about this:

1: Is it possible to render a canvas with OpenGL so that I can display my drawing on the chromecast remote display?

2: is there any good 2d paint tutorial for OpenGL?

3: What else can I do beside this, to get the paint working on the remote display?